# Android In-App Billing app won't run

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm attempting to build a simple Android app using In-App Billing. I'm using a Nexus 7 2013 device to run and debug it. I just get the error message, "Unfortunately, your app has stopped." I've tried logging and inserting breakpoints, but it never even seems to get to the beginning of the code. I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial) and [this one](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial), and have only started working with them. My code:

```
package com.myknitcards.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.myknitcards.project.util.IabHelper;
import com.myknitcards.project.util.IabResult;
import com.myknitcards.project.util.Inventory;
import com.myknitcards.project.util.Purchase;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    private Button buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);

    private static final String TAG = "com.myknitcards.project";
    IabHelper mHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        clickButton.setEnabled(false);

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = 
                "mykeyhere";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new 
                IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                     public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
                 {
                           if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                             Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + 
                        result);
                           } else {             
                             Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                       }
                         }
                });
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view) {
        clickButton.setEnabled(false);
        buyButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

My LogCat reads:

10-14 17:30:07.458: D/AndroidRuntime(10207): Shutting down VM
10-14 17:30:07.458: W/dalvikvm(10207): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41be2ba8)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207): Process: com.myknitcards.project, PID: 10207
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myknitcards.project/com.myknitcards.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at com.myknitcards.project.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:24)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207):    ... 11 more
10-14 17:30:10.701: I/Process(10207): Sending signal. PID: 10207 SIG: 9

I don't know where to even start. Why would it not be able to instantiate the activity? BTW, I have downloaded the TrivialDrive sample from Google's Developer site, and it will run on my tablet, so that's not the issue. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the last "Caused by" in the stack trace listing (that is the first exception):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 10-14 17:30:07.458: E/AndroidRuntime(10207): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)

The doc says `findViewById(int id)` returns "The view if found or null otherwise." But it's not returning null, it's throwing NPE.

You could look at the source code for Activity.java:1884 or set an exception breakpoint to find out what null it's tripping over.

Perhaps it couldn't load the needed layout resources or manifest or other resources. Or maybe a resource is missing.

Here's a link to the source code for ?? version of [Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java). It says:

```
public View findViewById(int id) {
    return getWindow().findViewById(id);
}
```

So `getWindow()` must be returning `null`. The doc says it returns "The current window, or null if the activity is not visual."

Apparently it thinks your main activity is not "visual." Is your main activity declared to be a Service?

Comment: Jerry, thank you - the problem was that I was instantiating the buttons outside of the onCreate method. This is a modification of the tutorial's text, but I did that so that I could call them in the buttonClicked method also. I moved the instantiation into both methods and it works fine (until the next error, of course, but so it goes). I'm guessing it doesn't work before onCreate because Java can't use R until onCreate is called, but that is totally a guess. If you know the reason and could pass it along, that'd be great. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. I think `super.onCreate()` (the first step in the activity lifecycle) creates the window. Also `findViewById(int id)` says "Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle)" so that reveals a dependency. `R` contains literals so they should be available to Java as soon as that class is demand-loaded.